# Grails app not creating table in database upon running

Tags: database, oracle, grails

I'm trying to setup my grails app so that it creates the below table in the database upon `run-app`.

```
class MyClass {

    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        firstName (blank: false)
        lastName  (blank: false)
    }
}a
```

I have my DataSource.groovy file configured to connect to my Oracle database.

```
dataSource {
    url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<HOST_NAME>)(PORT=<PORT_NUMBER>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<SERVICE_NAME_URL>)))'
    username = 'wl_user'
    password = 'my_password'
    dbCreate = 'update'
    logSql = true
    driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect'
    pooled = true
    properties {
        validationQuery = 'select 1 dbcp_connection_test from dual'
        testOnBorrow = true
        testOnReturn = true
        maxActive = 4
        maxIdle = 1
        initialSize = 0
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be creating when I fire up the app. Anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: What is your dataSource `dbCreate` setting?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - the code shows - it's `update`

Comment: Huh, I skipped right over it. Well, there goes that. Ensure that whichever environment being used is set up with dbCreate='update'.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa in which file would I set that? Would that be in my application.yml file?

Comment: If you have an application.yml file, why are you using DataSource.groovy?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed both. First time setting up a grails app. So if I only need one, I'll use the application.yml. And I should also set my database connections in there too?

Comment: Yes. Note that Grails has changed significantly over the years, so if you follow instructions on some website, they are likely to be outdated. Especially since you're using Grails 3. So as much as possible, stick to the Grails 3 documentation to save yourself those headaches. And, welcome to Grails development :)